# Laravel Object error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i'm trying to add users  with specified roles into database , an error indicates

> "ErrorException in 748460238d8f66b0fe4acb25c19f24f04b548bd9.php line 25:
>   Trying to get property of non-object (View: ..\views\admin\users\index.blade.php)".

below are the `UserModel`, `index.blade.php` and the controller.

What's wrong ?

Great thanks

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Role;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\UsersRequest;

class AdminUsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //

        $users=User::all();
        return view('admin.users.index',compact('users'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //

        $roles = Role::lists('name','id')->all();
        return view('admin.users.create',compact('roles'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(UsersRequest $request)
    {
        //
         User::create($request->all());
        //return $request->all();


      return redirect('/admin/users');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
        return view('admin.users.show');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        return view('admin.users.edit');
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

```css
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token'
    ];

    public function role(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

```html
@extends('layouts.admin')



@section('content')

<h1>Users</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
              <th>Role</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Created</th>
              <th>Updated</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @if($users)
@foreach($users as $user)

      <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->role->name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->is_active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'No active' }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
          <td>{{ $user->updated_at }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
@endif
    </tbody>
  </table>


@stop
```

Migrations schema:

```js
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('roles');
    }
}
```

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullabe();
            $table->integer('is_active')->default(0);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: role_id is a foreign key in user table

Comment: check [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship

Comment: Why haven't you responded to anyone's answers? If you want free help, at least do your end of the deal and provide some closure to your issue. Who helped? Who didn't? Is it fixed now? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your blade file, try this:

```
 @foreach($users as $user)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
    <td>
        @if($user->role)
           {{ $user->role->name }}
        @else
          No role defined
        @endif
    </td>
    <td>{{ $user->is_active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'No active' }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ $user->updated_at }}</td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: the erros disapper but either i select the admin wich displayed into a select , the role is always No role defined

Answer (score 0):

Update function role() in User model like below:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token'
];

public function role(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','role_id');
}
}
```

Comment: ErrorException in 748460238d8f66b0fe4acb25c19f24f04b548bd9.php line 42:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\codehacking\resources\views\admin\users\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Add `role_id` and `is_active` in `$fillable` inside `User` model to save those record in users table.

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','role_id','is_active',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check what is on line 25 of `748460238d8f66b0fe4acb25c19f24f04b548bd9.php`?. Find the file and check it.

My first assumption is that you're not using `User::with('role')->get()` instead of `User::all()`. You can't access `$user->role->name` without the relation loaded.